# Is it possible to record audio from multiple microphones at the same time?

Tags: android, audio

I am developing an app that makes use of an Android device microphone and Bluetooth headset. The audio is transmitted from the microphone to the headset immediately. My use case might greatly benefit from the so called "audio beamforming", when the audio signal is amplified in a specific physical direction while sound from all the other directions is attenuated. As far as I understand, this technique requires at minimum 2 audio inputs running synchronously, which in my case should be the microphone of the device itself and the microphone on the Bluetooth headset.

Is this feasible in Android SDK or NDK? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you done any research prior asking or atbleast checked existing APIs? If not, this is what you should be doing as starting point.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yes I did. Creating two different `AudioRecord` instances with different `preferredDevice` setting doesn't work. Logs show `E/AudioRecord: start() status -3`